# Why is the MediaPlayer force closing my app?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to make a countdown timer that plays a sound when it reaches 0 but whenever it tries to play the sound it force closes. Im pretty sure that my code is right but I can't figure why it closes. Please help, why does this force close?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Chronometer;
import android.widget.Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


Button start, stop;
int minCount, secCount;
Chronometer count;
boolean viberate, running;
SharedPreferences getPrefs;
MediaPlayer alarm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initilize();
    count.start();

    count.setOnChronometerTickListener(new OnChronometerTickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
            if (running) {
                secCount--;
                updateDisplay();
            }

        }

    });
    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            running = true;
            alarm.release();

            if (minCount <= 0 && secCount <= 0) {
                nothing();
            }
        }
    });
    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            running = false;
        }
    });





protected void done() {
    // TODO

    boolean music = getPrefs.getBoolean("Sound", true);
    if (music && alarm != null) {
        alarm.start(); //line 179 this is the line that causes the force close

    }
    running = false;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Times Up!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

private void initilize() {

    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
    stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
    second = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.second);
    minute = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.minute);
    minCount = 1;
    secCount = 0;
    count = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer1);                           running = false;
    getPrefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    alarm = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.finished);
}

private void updateDisplay() {
    if (minCount <= 0 && secCount <= 0) {
        done();

    }
    if (secCount < 0) {
        minCount--;
        secCount = 59;
    }


    if (secCount < 0) {
        secCount = 59;
        second.setText("59");

    } else if (secCount <= 9) {
        second.setText("0" + secCount + "");
    } else {
        second.setText(secCount + "");
    }

    if (minCount < 0) {
        minCount = 59;
        minute.setText("59 :");

    } else if (minCount <= 9) {
        minute.setText("0" + minCount + " :");
    } else {
        minute.setText(minCount + " :");
    }


}


@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    alarm.release();
}

}
```

my logcat

```
12-12 19:55:50.423: E/AndroidRuntime(25573): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-12 19:55:50.423: E/AndroidRuntime(25573): java.lang.IllegalStateException
12-12 19:55:50.423: E/AndroidRuntime(25573):    at android.media.MediaPlayer._start(Native Method)
12-12 19:55:50.423: E/AndroidRuntime(25573):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.start(MediaPlayer.java:1025)
12-12 19:55:50.423: E/AndroidRuntime(25573):    at com.example.timer.MainActivity.done(MainActivity.java:179)
12-12 19:55:50.423: E/AndroidRuntime(25573):    at com.example.timer.MainActivity.updateDisplay(MainActivity.java:209)
12-12 19:55:50.423: E/AndroidRuntime(25573):    at com.example.timer.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:207)
12-12 19:55:50.423: E/AndroidRuntime(25573):    at com.example.timer.MainActivity$1.onChronometerTick(MainActivity.java:47)
12-12 19:55:50.423: E/AndroidRuntime(25573):    at android.widget.Chronometer.dispatchChronometerTick(Chronometer.java:279)
12-12 19:55:50.423: E/AndroidRuntime(25573):    at android.widget.Chronometer$1.handleMessage(Chronometer.java:271)
12-12 19:55:50.423: E/AndroidRuntime(25573):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-12 19:55:50.423: E/AndroidRuntime(25573):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-12 19:55:50.423: E/AndroidRuntime(25573):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4978)
12-12 19:55:50.423: E/AndroidRuntime(25573):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-12 19:55:50.423: E/AndroidRuntime(25573):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-12 19:55:50.423: E/AndroidRuntime(25573):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
12-12 19:55:50.423: E/AndroidRuntime(25573):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
12-12 19:55:50.423: E/AndroidRuntime(25573):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: If it force closes, LogCat made a stack trace. You should edit your question to add the LogCat output.

Comment: `music == true` should be `if(music)` don't use `==` with boolean

Comment: @codeMagic You can use `==` with boolean, it's just that it's convention to not use `==`.

Comment: Yes, I realize that but its best to stick with convention in most cases. I'm not saying that's the problem or it would be posted as an answer, I was just giving some helpful advice

Comment: @codeMagic, I know I just wanted to know why because sometimes I use it. But thanks A--C gives the answer.

Comment: Ok, sorry, didn't realize what you are after. I recently inherited a good app but doesn't follow convention in many ways so I have to tear it apart and make it more reusable and readable. If I see a boolean with `==` it's going to be confusing and make me think its an integer or something not a boolean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use

```
try {
            alarm.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

when you set data source to mediaplayer

Answer (score 0):

You have an illegalStateException, but your code looks fine.

```
alarm = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.finished);
```

Make sure that your stream finished is not an illegal format.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean when you say "Make sure that your stream finished is not an illegal format"? @LazyNinja

Comment: finished.mp3 or finished.wav in your raw folder. Is it a file supported by android? Try to replace it by working files just to make sure.